# Updating grpc server or client implementation after changing service definitions

Tags: grpc

Let's say you've gone through the whole process of making your service definition, generated your server and client stubs and implemented it. If you have an update to your service definition that modifies the method and adds new ones. Would I need to, for example, regenerate the stubs for the server and then copy the unchanged implementations from the old version of the code to the new stub or is there a better way?

Recently discovered gRPC so apologies if this is a stupid question.

Just have questions on the ideal process of updating definitions and seamlessly updating implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all changes (e.g. to `package`, `service`, `rpc`, `message` types) require regeneration of stubs in order that client and server implementations can reflect these changes; if you add e.g. a `rpc`, the only way to use it in code is to regenerate stubs.

A general approach is that your build process will be triggered by protobuf changes to regenerate stubs (often in the same repo) and signal<sup>1</sup> to implementors that a new release is available.

Protobufs are designed to include backward- and forward-compatible features. As long as you adhere to [best practices](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/dos-donts/), clients|servers using stubs from non-current releases will continue to be able to produce|consume messages (from current clients|servers) albeit without seeing any additions (e.g. added `rpc`, `message` or fields).

`message`'s organize fields but, as with other compiled code, `message` and field names are **not** included in the on-the-wire (binary|serialized) messages. The binary message uses a schema and the binary message's field numbers to deserialize `message`'s. For this reason, it is possible (though not advised) to rename `message`'s and fields as long as the type and field numbers are **not** changed.

A good resource is [Protocol Buffers Best Practices for Backward and Forward Compatibility](https://earthly.dev/blog/backward-and-forward-compatibility/)

<sup>1</sup> either by push manually (e.g. email) or pull automatically (e.g. Go Module updates become available).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helped me get a better perspective. Have a question about the implementors side. Is there a way to sort of merge an old implemented stub with a new stub? For example, let's say an implementor already implemented the methods in a previous update. Now a new rpc is added, is it possible to regenerate a new stub which includes the old implementation as well as the new empty rpc. 

To avoid an implementor having to copy function bodies over everytime there is a major update

Comment: The programming language specific stubs generated by `protoc` should be treated as a black box and not edited. The stubs generated by the Nth generation of protobuf sources will continue to work against generation N+1 as long as you follow the compatibility guidelines. When the stubs for generation N+1 are generated, these should be published or distributed as a unit. Your developers code will need to be recompiled (anyway) and should be recompiled against the stubs as a unit. If existing methods are unchanged, the code that implements them will be unchanged too.

Comment: Please consider asking follow-up questions as new questions rather than comments.